# Simplify the Doctrine query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

### I am new to Doctrine ORM or any ORM

```
$em = Zend_Registry::getInstance ()->entitymanager;         
$p = $em->createQuery ( "               
SELECT u                
FROM Teon_Model_User u              
WHERE u.app_auth IN (:app_auth)" );                     
$p->setParameter ( 'app_auth', $app_auth );         
$array = $p->getArrayResult();      
$customer_id = $array[0]['customer_id']; 


$p = $em->createQuery ( "               
SELECT p                
FROM Teon_Model_Purchase p              
WHERE p.customer IN (:customer_id)" );                  
$p->setParameter ( 'customer_id', $customer_id );       
$array = $p->getArrayResult();      
$purchase_id = $array[0]['id'];      

$p = $em->createQuery ( "               
SELECT pm               
FROM Teon_Model_PurchaseManual pm               
WHERE pm.purchase_id IN (:purchase_id)" );                  
$p->setParameter ( 'purchase_id', $purchase_id );       
$array = $p->getArrayResult();      
$m_id = $array[0]['manual_id'];
```

Can you simplify this query, it looks so stupid, I am using Doctrine in zend framework

this query is to authenticate the user whether he has manual_id in his purchases by supplying a authentication code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the 2 simple way i could think of to do this:

```
<?php

$em = Zend_Registry::getInstance()->entitymanager;

// 1st way
$user = $em->getRepository('Teon_Model_User')->findOneByAppAuth($app_auth);
$user->getCustomerId();

// 2nd way
$user = $em->getRepository('Teon_Model_User')->findOneBy(array(
    'app_auth' => $app_auth,
));
$user->getCustomerId();
```